# i wanna chance the row color when if row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision

Tags: reactjs

```
const row = this.state.estimateItemList[i];
if (row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision) {
  return row.style.color = 'red';  // i wanna change row color here set the css
 }
 return row;
};
```

I want to change the row color when the condition `row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision` holds. How can I prevent the change of `this.color`? It is my first react project.

Comment: Can you share more code of yours for better solution

Answer (score 1):

Without knowledge of your `row` model, it's hard to understand what you want exactly, but this is one way of doing what you ask (I went off of what was defined for `row`)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.estimateItemList.map((row) => {
        const style = {};
        if(row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision){
          style.color = 'red';
        }
        return (
          <div style={style}>{row.revision}</div>
        );
      )}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a array of items in a react state is not advisable as in your case it is hard to interpret what the row model is doing and it is advisable to keep only the row 
which satisfies the condition in a state like the following.`

```
if (row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision) {
      this.setState({
           row_revision:row.revision
          });
 }`
```

and apply the class during render for the current state of row revision.Hope it helps.

Comment: i try add to render but what is the row_revision sir is it variable?

Comment: its just name of a state...u can name it whatever you want..but the thing i am saying is you should avoid having an array like selectedEstimate in a state and try to put only the value which gets changed in a state.